# Creating a NavigationDrawer programmatically

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How to implement a NavigationDrawer that is created programmatically? So far, all the tutorials I found include XML implementation for the layout. I need to avoid that, as the drawer is part of a library I want to embed in some other Android project.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be necessary to avoid resources entirely. If you're using the latest version of Eclipse, you can build a library as you normally would a full application, complete with a manifest, image resources, string resources, and yes, XML layouts. For more information, see this page from Google's developer docs: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Comment: well i want the library to be a single jar, rather than a project that will embed in another project - so i dont want to go down this route